# Mono and RegistrationBuilder (MEF) throwing System.InvalidProgramException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mono, mef

I'm trying to use xsp4 on Lubunutu to run a C# ASP.NET (ASP.NET v4, MVC 5, .NET 4.5) website.  On Mono 4.2.1.102/6dd2d0d, I am getting the following error:

```
System.InvalidProgramException
Invalid IL code in System.ComponentModel.Composition.Registration.RegistrationBuilder:.ctor (): method body is empty.
```

JetBrains dotPeek confirms that the constructor is empty but I'm really not sure why this is a problem!  Does anyone have any insight or debugging suggestions for this?

Comment: I don't know if MEF has ever been tested successfully with Mono. I'm thinking you might have more luck by using the alternative: MonoAddins (which also works in .NET): https://github.com/mono/mono-addins